# Changing an CSS Property for once at opening of the website

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change a style of a class just once when the website is opened. How can I do this with css?

Comment: be more specific while asking a question, share your code tell us what you did and what you expected, what is happening etc

Comment: css would be loaded immediately on website load though?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you try triggering `javascript` code that runs once the page is finished loading? One way to do that is `<body onload='my_function()'>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `jQuery` function `$(document).ready()` to trigger css style changing after the page has loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h1.to_change').css("color","blue");
});
```

```css
h1 { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1 class='to_stay'>This is a red header</h1>
<h1 class='to_change'>This was a red header</h1>
```

Comment: It can be without js only css....

Comment: @לבנימלכה can you elaborate? the OP requested the css to be changed after the page has loaded, meaning to override the original css

Comment: so use `h1{color:red}` and `.to_change{color:blue}`

Comment: @לבנימלכה I know it can be done from css file. put the OP requested to change the style after the CSS is done loading. I only made this as an example. He did not ask for this particular change